# Error in converting tensorflow BERT checkpoints to pytorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I downloaded tensorflow checkpoints for domain specific bert model and extracted the zip file into the folder pretrained_bert which contains the following the three files

> model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
>
> model.ckpt.index
>
> model.ckpt.meta

I used the following code to convert tensorflow checkpoints to pytorch

```
import torch

from pytorch_transformers.modeling_bert import BertConfig, BertForPreTraining, load_tf_weights_in_bert


tf_checkpoint_path="pretrained_bert/model.ckpt"
bert_config_file = "bert-base-cased-config.json"
pytorch_dump_path="pytorch_bert"

config = BertConfig.from_json_file(bert_config_file)
print("Building PyTorch model from configuration: {}".format(str(config)))
model = BertForPreTraining(config)

# Load weights from tf checkpoint
load_tf_weights_in_bert(model, config, tf_checkpoint_path)

# Save pytorch-model
print("Save PyTorch model to {}".format(pytorch_dump_path))
torch.save(model.state_dict(), pytorch_dump_path)
```

I got this error when I ran the above code

> NotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to
> find any matching files for pretrained_bert/model.ckpt

Any help is really appreciated............

Comment: As you said, I have changed the path, but I got the same error

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. You have actually given it properly. However, I do see that you have given the relative path. Try providing the absolute path.

Comment: Thanks, it worked after specifying the absolute path.

Comment: Hi @KalyanKatikapalli, I am having the same problem. I put absolute path already but still giving me the same error. Do you have any advice? Thanks

Comment: In the code, absolute path must be specified for the variables

"tf_checkpoint_path",
"bert_config_file" and 
"pytorch_dump_path".
When relative path is specified, the model is unable to find the corresponding files.

Answer (score 0):

In the code,  absolute path must be specified for the variables

- tf_checkpoint_path
- bert_config_file
- pytorch_dump_path

When relative path is specified, the model is unable to find the corresponding files.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says,

> Failed to find any matching files for pretrained_bert/model.ckpt

It might be possible that your program may not be executed from the location which has a folder named `pretrained_bert` or it does doesn't have the `pretrained_bert/model.ckpt*` files.

So, first, ensure the presence of the file. Further, you can follow the below steps:

Kindly provide absolute path instead of the relative path. This reverifies the presence of files. In case if you still want to use the relative path, do verify the path from where the current execution takes place, and then use `../` if you want to navigate up to the parent directory.